# Identifying outliers with differnt numbers of data points per sample in Execl or R

Tags: r, excel, matrix, outliers

I am trying to identify Outiers in a Dataset, where each sample has a different amount of Data points.
Meaning the Matrix length differs from sample to sample.
Since I am working on a big data set it is really Time consuming to change matrix length manually.
I hope to find a solution for that problem here:)
Also suggestions for R are welcome!

[Here is an example data set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfqnG.png)

```
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    Time = c(5, 17, 18, 24, 4, 8, 9, 10, 16, 15, 4, 13, 9, 17), 
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -14L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))
```

I used the Function:

```
=IF(OR(B2>QUARTILE($B$2:$B$5;3)+1,5*(QUARTILE($B$2:$B$5;3)-QUARTILE($B$2:$B$5;1));F2<QUARTILE($B$2:$B$51;1)-1,5*(QUARTILE($B$2:$B$5;3)-QUARTILE($B$2:$B$5;1)));1;0)
```

But as described above, with that approach I need to change the matrix manually from sample to sample.
The outlier is then identified with "1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways, with `quantile/IQR` and with the statistics `boxplot` uses. The latter is fastest.

```r
outlier <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  qq <- quantile(x, c(1/4, 3/4), na.rm = na.rm)
  iqr <- IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  x < qq[1L] - 1.5*iqr | x > qq[2L] + 1.5*iqr
}
outlier_bp <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out
}

sapply(iris[1:4], outlier) |> head()
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> [1,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [2,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [3,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [4,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [5,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [6,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
sapply(iris[1:4], outlier_bp) |> head()
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> [1,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [2,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [3,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [4,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [5,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE
#> [6,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE

library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  qnt = sapply(iris[1:4], outlier),
  bxp = sapply(iris[1:4], outlier_bp)
)
print(mb, order = "median")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
#>   bxp 233.3 321.15 388.300 365.55 454.15  738.9   100   b
#>   qnt 551.2 742.65 875.958 817.95 949.30 3593.9   100  a
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

After the OP comments, here is a better use case for the function `outlier` above.
Split `Time` by `ID` and apply the function to each sub-vector. This is done with `tapply`.

```r
i_out <- with(df1, tapply(Time, ID, FUN = outlier))
i_out
#> $`1`
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

out <- with(df1, tapply(Time, ID, FUN = \(x) x[outlier(x)]))
out
#> $`1`
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $`2`
#> numeric(0)
#> 
#> $`3`
#> numeric(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Or with a function that returns the outliers, not an index to them,

```r
outlier2 <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  qq <- quantile(x, c(1/4, 3/4), na.rm = na.rm)
  iqr <- IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  i <- x < qq[1L] - 1.5*iqr | x > qq[2L] + 1.5*iqr
  x[i]
}

with(df1, tapply(Time, ID, FUN = outlier2))
#> $`1`
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $`2`
#> numeric(0)
#> 
#> $`3`
#> numeric(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this Code detects only Outliers in the whole data set, not within a sample (see description above). So it is not working for my dataset.

Comment: e.g.  "5" is only within Sample 1 an outlier , not within the whole data set. I am looking for a solution that can detect outliers within the samples of different length

Comment: @HildiSchild See if the edit solves it.

Answer (score 1):

A lazy approach would be `rstatix::is_outlier()`,
though its list of package dependencies is difficult to justify for just an outlier detector.

```r
df <- structure(list(Time = c(5, 17, 18, 24, 4, 8, 9, 10, 16, 15, 4, 13, 9, 17), 
                     ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))

# add another outlier:
df$Time[14] <- 100

dplyr::mutate(df, out = rstatix::is_outlier(Time), .by = ID)
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#>     Time    ID out  
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
#>  1     5     1 TRUE 
#>  2    17     1 FALSE
#>  3    18     1 FALSE
#>  4    24     1 FALSE
#>  5     4     2 FALSE
#>  6     8     2 FALSE
#>  7     9     2 FALSE
#>  8    10     3 FALSE
#>  9    16     3 FALSE
#> 10    15     3 FALSE
#> 11     4     3 FALSE
#> 12    13     3 FALSE
#> 13     9     3 FALSE
#> 14   100     3 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>